# Why isn't disabling the WordPress wpautop function working?

Tags: php, css

I am using WordPress with TablePress and I have disabled wpautop on content and posts. But, I am still receiving line breaks between list items and paragraph tags. I even tried downloading a plug-in for wpautop and it isn't disabling that feature. What can I do to stop this madness? Thanks!!!

Comment: *I have disabled wpautop* -- how did you disable it?

Comment: PLease always post extract of your config or code if possible to receive help faster. Be explicit of what you tried, the more details you add, the less likely you will either get down votes or no help from users

Answer (score 1):

This may not be wpautop adding line breaks but rather TinyMCE. In code view, do you see the line breaks? If not, then you may have a plugin parsing your content and applying wpautop. If so, then you may have to [edit the TinyMCE settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE).

Comment: I went into the editor and disabled it. I then went into the MYSQL database itself and checked the post content. There are not any breaks shown in the database, but it still appears in the webpage itself.

Comment: I fixed it. I just went into wp-includes/post-template.php and added the follow code to the_conent function $content = str_ireplace("<br />", "", $content);